# How to use read and write past BUFSIZ in C

Tags: c, linux, file, system, stdio

For an assignment, I'm supposed to create two methods: Method one will `read()` and `write()` the input file to an empty output file, one byte at a time (slowly).

The other method will instead use `char buf[BUFSIZ];` where `BUFSIZ` is from `<stdio.h>`. We are supposed to `read()` and `write()` with the `BUFSIZ` which will make things a lot faster.

The input file we test each method on is just a linux dictionary (`/dict/linux.words`).

I've correctly implemented method one, where I call `read()` and `write()` on one character at a time, copying the input file to the output file. Although it's very slow, it at least copies everything over.

My code for this looks like this:

```
// assume we have a valid, opened fd_in and fd_out file.
char buf;
while(read(fd_in, buf, 1) != 0)
    write(fd_out, buf, 1);
```

For method two however, where I use `BUFSIZ`, I am not able to transfer every single entry into the output file. It fails in the `z` entries, and doesn't write anymore.

So, my first try:

```
// assume we have a valid, opened fd_in and fd_out file
char buf[BUFSIZ];
while(read(fd_in, buf, BUFSIZ) != 0)
    write(fd_out, buf, BUFSIZ);
```

doesn't work.

I understand that `read()` will return either the number of bytes read or 0 if it is at the end of a file. The problem I'm having is understanding how I can compare `read()` to `BUFSIZ`, and then loop around and start `read()` at where it left off until I reach the real end of file.

Comment: ... `result = read(..); if (result < BUFSIZ) ..` seems somewhat obvious.

Comment: @Jongware It does now :/ I've been up for two days because of midterms/projects so my brain is pretty fried :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your file will most likely not be an exact multiple of `BUFSIZ` you need to check for the actual number of bytes read, so that the last block will be written correctly, e.g.

```
char buf[BUFSIZ];
ssize_t n;
while((n = read(fd_in, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0)
    write(fd_out, buf, n);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This makes a lot of sense.

Comment: please mind that your file can be an in most cases probably is larger than BUFSIZ, so you will have to do multiple reads

Comment: @Pandrei: yes, that's why the read and write calls are embedded in a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
this code:

// assume we have a valid, opened fd_in and fd_out file
char buf[BUFSIZ];
while(read(fd_in, buf, BUFSIZ) != 0)
    write(fd_out, buf, BUFSIZ);

leaves much to be desired, 
does not handle a short remaining char count at the end of the file, 
does not handle errors, etc.

a much better code block would be:

// assume we have a valid, opened fd_in and fd_out file
char buf[BUFSIZ];
int readCount;  // number of bytes read
int writeCount; // number of bytes written

while(1)
{
    if( 0 > (readCount = read(fd_in, buf, BUFSIZ) ) )
    { // then, read failed
         perror( "read failed" );
         exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, read successful

    if( 0 == readCount )
    {  // then assume end of file
        break; // exit while loop
    }

    // implied else, readCount > 0

    if( readCount != (writeCount = write( fd_out, buf, readCount ) ) )
    { // then, error occurred
        perror( "write failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, write successful
} // end while
```

Note:  I did not include the closing of input/output files statements
         before each call to exit() however, that does need to be added